# Task with Action Delegate accepting string parameter

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, delegates

I have just started with parallel programming. I want to create an action delegate method that print a message on console. When I chenge `Action<string>` to `Action<object>` and `PritMessage` parameter to to object its work but with '`string` compiler throws an error.

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Task(System.Action, object)'.
>   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Action<string>' to
>   'System.Action<object>'

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string message = "test";
    Action<string> print = PrintMessage;
    Task task = new Task(print, message); 
    task.Start();
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void PrintMessage(string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you examine the [`Task` constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.task.aspx), you'll see that you can't create a task with Action which accepts something other than no parameters or single `object` parameter.

For this particular sample you can simply run the `Task` with lambda, like this:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    PrintMessage(message);
}
```

However, better approach is to change signature and cast an in-parameter:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var message = "test";
    Task task = new Task(PrintMessage, message); 
    task.Start();
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void PrintMessage(object messageObj)
{
    var message = messageObj as string;
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

Or simply print the object in Console:

```
static void PrintMessage(object message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```